# How do I make webpages in adobe flash cs5?

Tags: flash-cs5

I am trying to make a very simple website for a class I am taking.  I am supposed to make 3 pages and 3 buttons connecting to the pages. The pages are just drawings of the words of what the pages are.  I need to know how to make multiple pages of different designs and how to make the buttons and then I need to know how to link them together to make a webpage.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it's not a great idea to make webpages out of Flash. You want to use Flash for development in areas where web standards are not up to par such as games, advanced graphics, etc..

However there are essentially two ways to accomplish what you want.

## Method One

Make a single Flash app with the Flash IDE, pubis it for the web. This will give you a flash.swf file and a flash.html file. You want to put the html file on your server and link it to your flash.swf file.

## Method Two

Same as method one but create a different flash.swf for each page so you have different flash.swf files for each webpage.

Comment: well my teacher showed us how to do it..so i know that we can..i just forgot how he did it thats all.

Comment: Your teacher must be a masochist. If you are just trying to create a web page and flash doesn't matter then I wouldn't use it. Otherwise you need to read up on using the Flash IDE and how to creates animations as that is what flash 'web pages' are.